# Tensorflow: sess.run returns same output label

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-recognition, tensor

I have implemented a tensorflow image classifier and in the end, `sess.run` returns same np array everytime. I have no clue why is it happening?

Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong?

```
def predict():

  train = data.train
  test = data.test
  tf.reset_default_graph()

  (n_x, m) = train.images.T.shape #n_x is 784
  X = xPlaceholder(n_x) ##return X of shape(784,)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
      new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('~/trained-model.ckpt.meta')
      new_saver.restore(sess, '~/trained-model.ckpt')
      #y_pred is the softmax of last output layer; 
      y_pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('y_pred:0')
      #imageprepare function return (784,) np array
      output_label = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={X: imageprepare('jean.jpeg')}) 
      print(output_label)
```

The output label is returned as np array with shape [10,] where 10 are the number of labels. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code you don't execute your restored graph at all. You created a separate placeholder `X`, which doesn't belong to restored graph pipeline. And you execute variable `pred` which is out of the scope you provided (not defined here).

If you just need inference, you can pass to session.run Operation (variables, placeholders) names as a string:

```
session.run('y_pred:0', feed_dict={'x_placheholder:0':numpy_image})
```

Make sure you set those variable names when you construct the graph (i.e. `tf.placeholder(shape, name='x_placholder')`).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply. As mentioned, I added the placeholder in the train function but still, it shows the same output. I have added the code for your reference https://codeshare.io/2jO4oR. Thank you for your help!!